# iOS App Authentication Without UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, flask, flask-login

Is there a way to authenticate a user **without** a webview from a Flask(Python) backend?

This is my backend login code:

```
@app.route('/login/', methods=['POST'])
def login():
    params = json.loads(request.data)
    username = params['username']
    password = params['password']
    u = User.query.filter_by(username=username).first()
    if u:
        if utils.check_password_hash(password, u.pw_hash):
            login_user(u)
            return ('', 200)
        else:
            return ('', 400)
    else:
        return ('', 400)
```

Comment: I hope that this question is fairly general so it is helpful for future users. If you would like me to add anything to the question, please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: You could use `NSURLConnection` to perform a `GET` or `POST` request to your API endpoint.

Comment: That logs in the user, I have that at the moment, but it does not authenticate the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you most certainly can do this.  This is how I typically do it, change it to your needs (keep in mind that NSJSONSerialization is only available in iOS 5+):

```
@property (nonatomic) NSOperationQueue *basicQueue; //add this to your header or as an instance variable

-(void)logMeIn:(NSString *)username password:(NSString *)password {

basicQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

NSDictionary *userCredentialsDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:username, @"username", password, @"password", nil];
NSData *encodedDict = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:userCredentialsDict options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:NULL];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://yoursite.com/login"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:encodedDict];
[request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:basicQueue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*) response;
    NSString *stringFromData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    if (httpResponse.statusCode == 200) {
        //do stuff
        NSLog(@"Received data, parsed into string: %@", stringFromData);
    } else {
        //do error stuff or whatever
    }

}];
```

}

For more information, 
check out

- https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html
- https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html
- http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Thank you so so much. Very helpful. :) Will read up on the Apple Developer links.

Comment: Interesting solution. After the `httpResponse.statusCode == 200` has been accepted, how do you store the session so that consecutive access to the webservice doesn't require any further login request? Or is it a common way to pass username/password upon each request to the server?